# reload captcha image with jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, captcha

I want to have a reload button beside my captcha image to reload it with jquery in codeigniter. I searched the net to find a solution for it, but all I found confused me.

this is my controller:

```
function create_captcha()
{                                
    $expiration = time()-300; // Two hour limit
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM captcha WHERE captcha_time < ".$expiration);
    $vals = array(
                //'word'         => 'Random word',
                'word_length' => 4,
                'img_path' => './uploads/captcha/',
                'img_url' => base_url().'uploads/captcha/',
                'font_path' => './system/fonts/texb.ttf',
                'img_width' => '110',
                'img_height' => '30',
                'expiration' => '3600'
            );

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);

    //puts in the db
    $captchadata = array(
                'captcha_id'    => '',
                'captcha_time'  => $cap['time'],
                'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address(),
                'word'          => $cap['word']
            );

    $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $captchadata);
    $this->db->query($query);

    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') echo $cap['image'];
    else return $cap['image'];
```

and this is my view:

```
<div class="captcha-area">
    <? echo form_input('captcha', '', 'class="field text captcha"')?>
    <div id="cap-img">
        <? echo $image;?>
    </div>
    <a title="reload" class="reload-captcha" href="#"><img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>images/reload.png" /></a>                                
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <script>
      $(function(){
          var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
          $('.reload-captcha').click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              $('.captcha-img').attr('src', base_url+'dashboard/create_captcha?'+Math.random());
          });
       });
 </script>
```

**EDIT:**

this is the source code after loading the site

```
<div class="captcha-area">
   <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" class="field text captcha">
   <div id="cap-img">
       <img src="http://example.com/uploads/captcha/1382346264.1026.jpg" width="110" height="30" class="captcha-img" style="border:0;" alt=" ">
   </div>
   <a title="reload" class="reload-captcha" href="#"><img src="http://example.com/images/reload.png"></a>                                
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and when I click on the reload button it changes the src attribute to something like:

```
<img src="http://example.com/dashboard/create_captcha?0.8049291325733066" width="110" height="30" class="captcha-img" style="border:0;" alt=" ">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed Ruhan Kumar's code a little bit and could get the satisfying code:

```
<script>
     $(function(){
         var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
         $('.reload-captcha').click(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                 url:base_url+'admin/dashboard/create_captcha',
                 success:function(data){
                     $('.captcha-img').replaceWith(data);
                 }
             });            
          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Append your `controller name` and use `ajax` like,

```
$(function(){
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    $('.reload-captcha').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url:base_url+'dashboard/create_captcha?'+Math.random(),
           success:function(data){
              $('.captcha-img').attr('src', data);
           }
        });            
    });
});
```

Comment: of course I had the controller but I omitted it here.
I edited the post, have a look at it.

Comment: @Afshin see I've changed my answer you need to use `ajax` for that

Comment: this time it put whole html code in src attribute. it seems like: `src="<html>....</html>"`

Comment: I changed your code a little bit, and posted it below. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

> **#You may reload img by using ajax and javascript see my code**
>
> **#You must create a folder captcha in your CI root folder**
>
> **#The folder captcha permission to 777 or 666 mean(read, write for all)**
>
> **#Then look like ci/captcha**
>
> **#Then look like ci/application**
>
> **My html.php view**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function postRequest(strURL) 
    {
        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        { 
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) // IE 
        { 
             var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("your browser does not support AJAX");
            return;
        }
        xmlHttp.open('POST', strURL, true);

        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status==200) 
            {
                reload_captcha(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send(strURL);
    }
    
    function reload_captcha(str)
    {
        document.getElementById("captcha-img").innerHTML = str;
    }
    
    function get_captcha()
    {
        //<a href="#" onclick="JavaScript:get_captcha()" ></a>
        document.getElementById("captcha-img").innerHTML = '<img src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/loader.gif'); ?>" height="35" width="37" />';
        var url="<?php echo base_url('index/reload_captcha'); ?>";
        postRequest(url);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Human test</label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5" name="captcha" value="" />
<span id="captcha-img" class="captcha-img">
    <?php echo $captcha_img; ?>
</span>
<a href="#reload" onclick="JavaScript:get_captcha()" ><img class="reload-img" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/img/reload.png'); ?>" alt="reload" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

> **My index.php Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('date');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Security','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_captcha');
        
        if($this->form_validation->run() == False)
        {
            $data['captcha_img'] = $this->get_captcha();
        
        $this->load->view('html',$data);
    }
}

private function _generate_string($min, $max)
{
    $pool = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $pool = str_shuffle($pool);
    $str = '';
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
    }
    
    return $str;
}
    
public function get_captcha()
{
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    
    $word = $this->_generate_string(2,5);
    
    $vals = array(
                    'word' => $word,
        'img_path'   => './captcha/',
        'img_url'    => base_url().'captcha/',
        'img_width'  => 120,
        'img_height' => 35,
        'border' => 0, 
        'font_path' => './system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'expiration' => 3600 //1 houre
    );
    
    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    
    $this->session->set_userdata($cap['word']);
        
    return $cap['image'];
}

public function reload_captcha()
{
    $new_captcha = $this->get_captcha();
    echo "".$new_captcha;
}

public function check_cap_tcha()
{
    $session_captcha_code = $this->session->userdata('word');
        
    if($session_captcha_code == $user_captcha_code)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', "Security code does not match !");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

> **And after all it's work well !**